# TyperError when converting NaN's into number in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, nan

I have a DataFrame `df` that looks as follows and I'm trying to convert all cases where there is a `NaN` in the `closing_price` column into 100.

```
   maturity_dt              pay_freq_cd   coupon closing_price FACE_VALUE  
0   2017-06-30 00:00:00.0           2    0.625      99.96875        100   
1   2015-07-15 00:00:00.0           2      1.6         99.47        100   
2   2018-06-15 00:00:00.0           2    1.125      100.3906        100   
3   2015-07-13 00:00:00.0           2      2.1           NaN        100
```

I try to do that with the code below, but I get the error `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`
 in the line `price_array = np.where(np.isnan(price_array), 100, price_array)`.

```
price_array = df['closing_price'].values
price_array = np.where(np.isnan(price_array), 100, price_array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pandas' [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method instead. In your case you can write:

```
df['closing_price'].fillna(100)
```

This replaces the `NaN` values in the 'closing_price' column with the value 100. Different data types are handled correctly by Pandas. (Remember to assign the new column back to the DataFrame or use `inplace=True`.)

---

The error you see is a result of the 'closing_price' column having the `object` data type. `np.isnan` expects an array of float values. To get around this, you can cast the column to floating type with

```
df['closing_price'] = df['closing_price'].astype(float)
```

...and then use your method as normal (although I'd still favour `fillna()`).

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that some of the values were `int`'s, but will go ahead with the `df['closing_price'].fillna(100)` method.